# Proving if the limit of a Cauchy sequence can be non-existent

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

When talking about non convergence of Cauchy sequences, the only examples I can found are the ones in which the sequences converges outside the space (X,d), ans so it does not converge in X.

Can I have a Cauchy sequence that is not convergent not because it's limits falls outside the space but  because it is $+-\infty $ or because  it does not exist like $ (-1)^n$?

I already ruled ot  the first case, since every Cauchy sequence is bounded, so I still need to prove if the limit always exist or give a counterexample of a non-existent limit. How do I go about it?

Comment: Misread the post. Most likely no. Go to the completion of the metric space and you will have that the Cauchy sequence has to converge.

Comment: It is not the case that "the sequence converges outside the space $(X,d)$," but rather that the sequence does not converge in the space $(X,d)$, but *does* converge in the space $(\overline X, d)$, where $\overline X$ denotes the completion of $X$. There is a subtle, but important difference here. The definition of convergence of a sequence in a metric space only allows for one to speak of convergence to a point *within that space*.

Comment: @Math1000 ok, then can we have a Cauchy sequence that does not converge, not because it's limit falls outside the space, but because the limit is not unique, therefore it does not exist(like (-1)^n)?

Comment: $(-1)^n$ is not a Cauchy sequence...

Comment: @Math1000 I wasn't saying it was a Cauchy sequence, it was just an example of non-existent limit. The question is actually whether there exists a Cauchy sequence with this behavior